# PHP, identify a submitted form by unique value

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am trying to come up with a method to differentiate between form being submitted by a unique POST value. While in and of itself this is not that complex an issue my circumstances can lead to their being an issue.

```
while(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    require_once('login_form.php');
}
```

When a user goes to a page that requires the user to be logged in to view it. If someone lands on one of these pages and is not already logged in I am displaying the login form. The login form's action is itself, or rather the page being displayed. Now my issue comes when the page being displayed also has a form. I need a method to ensure that the $_POST data from the login form does not make it to the $_POST data from the page's form. Normally it would not be an issue except when when form inputs share the same name.

I am wanting a way to differentiate between forms using some unique value. I had been thinking about using HTML buttons for submission.

```
while(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    require_once('login_form.php');
}
if(isset($_POST['PAGE_FORM']) && !empty(PAGE_FORM)){
    unset($_POST);
}

<form name="PAGE_FORM">
    <button valuye="PAGE_FORM">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I had also thought about doing something like this instead.

```
while(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    require_once('login_form.php');
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && !empty($_SESSION['user'])){
        unset($_POST);
    }
}

<form name="PAGE_FORM">
    <button valuye="PAGE_FORM">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Let me know what you think. I would be interested in any other ideas you might have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of including the login_form, do a http redirect to a seperate login form.

Comment: +1. far better idea than some ugly mechanism to replace forms on the fly.

Comment: I had done it this way so that once a user logs in they arrive at the page they wanted to view without having to find it again. How would you go about incorporating this?

Comment: Before redirecting the user to the login page, store the destination url in the session. Upon successful login the script should check the session see whether there's an intended destination. If yes redirect the user and remove the destination url from session to prevent future issue.